# Node positioning algorithm for cytoscape

Tags: cytoscape.js

I need to build a network of nodes and edges for a hierarchical data set. I really liked the [wine and cheese sample](https://gist.github.com/maxkfranz/cde4db55e581d10405f5) in cytoscape.js and I am looking to implement my view in a similar fashion. I noticed that graph gets it's data from a remote api call which has the positions for each node pre-defined. Can anyone point me to some sample code which I could use to generate the positions in a similar manner?

Comment: the wine nodes are just aligned in two lines, and the cheese nodes use a plain network layout you can easily generate using what cyto already gives you out of the box.
providing absolute node positions in this case is pointless as the X and Y are meaningless.

Comment: The wine and cheese demo just uses Cytoscape layouts.  Since there's only one static graph, there's no advantage to running layouts dynamically each time -- so the positions are stored in the nodes.  @svarog has the right approach

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean by providing X and Y positions are meaningless, since I see the positions are specified by the api that is called within js code https://cdn.rawgit.com/maxkfranz/3d4d3c8eb808bd95bae7/raw Additionally, the layout I see is 'preset'. Doesn't that mean it uses the absolute positions? If the positions returned by the above api code are indeed used, then I am curious to know how the coordinates were generated in the first place (which might be a graph algorithm). Sample code would be useful. Thanks!

Comment: For clarification, I am more interested in the cheese nodes. I am assuming the positioning is not random

Comment: have you tried the cose layout ? it should provide you with a similar setup

Comment: Any physics/forces layout.  There are many supported.  You'll have to experiment with different ones and different parameters to see what works best for *your* data.  It's a different case for every graph.

Comment: That pointed me in the right direction. I ended up using an a force layout algorithm. Thanks for the help!